# How to optimize repeated checking if a point is in a polygon

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, oracle-spatial

**I have a `MultiPolygon` that represents a road and would like to find whether some GPS points fall within x distance from the road. My `geo_buf` below is `road.buffer(x)`. Using repeated `geo_buf.contains(Point)` is very slow, as shown in the profiling below (most of the time is spent running line 297).**

How can i optimize the speed?

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
from shapely.geometry import Point as shapely_Point

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   151                                           def filter_gps(gps_row, geo_buf):
   152    606446   62042960.0    102.3     83.3      pot = shapely_Point(gps_row['longitude'], gps_row['latitude'])
   153    606446   12433530.0     20.5     16.7      return geo_buf.contains(pot)



Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================

  294      1232      11850.0      9.6       0.0   if len(df_gps.index) > 1:
  295                                               geo_buf = shape(json.loads(srg_row['srg_buf']))
  296                                               # filter the GPS points
  297      1232   98465688.0  79923.4     68.4      df_filter = df_gps[df_gps.apply(lambda row: filter_gps(row, geo_buf), axis=1)]
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to optimize...

Comment: I want to optimize ”df_filter = df_gps[df_gps.apply(lambda row: filter_gps(row, geo_buf), axis=1)]“

Comment: you may be better off using geopandas: http://geopandas.org/

Comment: actually the GIS stack exchange site is better for this, have flagged it for migration

Comment: Migration was rejected. Please re-ask on GIS stack exchange; there are a lot more Q&As there about `shapely` performance.

Answer (score 0):

These may be helpful:

[Is there way to optimize speed of shapely.geometry.shape.contains(a_point) call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282306/is-there-way-to-optimize-speed-of-shapely-geometry-shape-containsa-point-call)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/165413#165413

(Not tested) I believe the fastest way to do this is to split your `Polygon` into many smaller `Polygon`s then use `geopandas.tools.sjoin`.

Comment: geo_buf is of the same type as patch.                                                                  '''from shapely.geometry import Point                                                                                                patch = Point(0.0, 0.0).buffer(10.0)                                                                      patch                                                                                        <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x...>'''

Comment: Ok, now i understand your problem. Have sent question edits for peer review.

Comment: If `geo_buf` is a circle then you should just calculate the haversine distance and filter instead of creating Point objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/vectorised-haversine-formula-with-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain my question very well. The geo_buffer is actually more like 'Polygon([(0,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,0)]].buffer(10)'，it's a MultiPolygon.
So the calculated distance is not possible.. I'm trying to use geopandas,
I need to convert the longitude and latitude  into '< shapely. Geometry. The point. The point at 0 x7f3997c54550 >
By 'Point (longtitude ，latitude), I have about 1000w GPS points. but the process has spent too much time.

Comment: The real background is probably a road. The bus travels on the road with a GPS trace. Suppose I want to extend this road to 30 meters on both sides,it is like geo_buf.Then find the gps point on the widened road.